# How to retrieve class name for T from Class<T> instance

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method that receives an instance of a typed Class as a parameter:

`public <T> someMethod(Class<T> theClass)`

I would like to get the name of the class that T represents.

I can get it like this:

`theClass.newInstance().getClass().getName()`

Is there a better way?

Background: My method builds a generic JPQL query based on the specified entity class.

**EDIT:**

The method in question actually looks like this:

`public <K> List<? extends SomeInterface<K>> someMethod(Class<? extends SomeInterface<K>> theClass, K thePk)`

...and Eng.Fouad was able to guess the typo that was caused my issue.

Comment: `theClass.getName()`?

Comment: That returns `Class`... It was the first thing I tried.  Maybe I was doing something else wrong at the time.  I'll give it another try.

Comment: No...no, it doesn't.  `theClass.newInstance().getClass()` just returns `theClass` again.

Comment: Well... My code is currently working with the above approach.

Comment: @jahroy The point is Louis' is much simpler: http://ideone.com/Ii04ve

Comment: (Voting to close since you're asking for a solution to a problem that doesn't seem to exist.)

Comment: @millimoose - Yes, it is much simpler.  Like I said, it was the first thing I tried and it did **NOT** work.  Then I tried the code from my example (which feels hacky) and it worked. This question was supposed to determine if there is a better way.

Comment: I think Eng.Fouad may have guessed what I did wrong the first time... I may have typed `theClass.getClass().getName()` out of habit.  I'll delete this question if he's right.

Comment: Make sure you type `theClass.getName()` and not `theClass.getClass()` or `theClass.getClass().getName()`.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 - Thanks.  I believe you and Eng.Fouad have guessed my accidental typing mistake.

Comment: @jahroy Surely the point of SO is not to guess what mistake you made in code you haven't shown us. This question doesn't seem to stand on merit.

Comment: @millimoose - That's fine.  Vote to close til your heart's content.  I'd prefer that it gets closed (actually I'll delete it in a moment).  I obviously wouldn't have asked the question if I had known the obvious solution wasn't working because of a typo!!  I'm thankful that somebody guessed my typo... but I had good intentions when I asked the question.  You seem to have misunderstood everything that took place here.

Comment: @jahroy Oh, I'm certainly not saying that your question shouldn't have been asked. (Although if you went through the work of trying to provide a complete test case it needn't have.) Just that having found out it was a brainfart should be reason enough to nuke it, it shouldn't be a condition of whether someone guesses the nature of the brainfart correctly.

Comment: @millimoose - Ok, understood.  I tried to delete the question, but I can't because there are answers.  Yes, I should have tested my test case... The issue is that I wrote the code a couple days ago and used the silly `newInstance` version shown above (after trying my _typoed_ code unsuccessfully).  Since then I've been wondering why the blatantly obvious solution didn't work... It never occurred to me that the only reason it didn't work is becuase of the garbage I typed by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
theClass.getName();
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  Whhen I tried it, I got `java.lang.Class`.  Like I said to Louis, maybe I was doing something else wrong at the time.  I'm going to try again.  Thanks.

Comment: @jahroy I bet you was trying using `theClass.getClass().getName()`.

Comment: @EngFouad - Ooh... maybe that was my brain fart.  Good call.

Comment: You were correct. I must have typed `getClass()` out of habit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code just returns the same thing.

```
theClass.newInstance().getClass().getName()
```

You have a `Class<T>` for which you create a new instance. Then you call `getClass()` on it, which returns `Class<T>` again.

You can just use `getName` on the original input parameter.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printName(String.class);
    printName(Integer.class);
}

public static <T> void printName(final Class<T> clazz) {
    System.out.println(clazz.getName());
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this.

```
public void printName(Object classObject){
    System.out.println(classObject.getClass().getName());
}
```

Instead of using parameters, the method accepts the object that represents the class.